# Retrofit response.body() is null, but JSON visible in Logcat, MODEL is correct

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I check everything a hundred times, but still my body is null.

Where my code

Entity

```
public class UserByID {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public UserByID(int id, String name, String email, String phoneNumber, String password) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setPassword(password);
    }

    //getters/setters
}
```

API

```
public interface UserAPI {
    @POST("/api/v1/users/register")
    Call<User> registerUser(@Body User user);

    @POST("/api/v1/users/auth")
    Call<UserByID> loginUser(@Body LoginForm form);
}
```

DataSource

```
public class UserRemoteDataSourceImpl implements UserRemoteDataSource {
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private MutableLiveData<User> user;
    private String URL = "";
    private String TAG = "UserRemoteDataSourceImpl";

    public UserRemoteDataSourceImpl(){
        this.retrofit = RetrofitFactory.getRetrofit(URL);
        this.user = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void registerUser(User user){
        UserAPI userAPI = retrofit.create(UserAPI.class);
        userAPI.registerUser(user).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "push isSuccessful");
                }
                else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "push not Successful");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure error");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public MutableLiveData<User> fetchUser(LoginForm loginForm) {
        UserAPI userAPI = retrofit.create(UserAPI.class);
        userAPI.loginUser(loginForm).enqueue(new Callback<UserByID>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserByID> call, Response<UserByID> response) {
                UserByID userByID = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG, response.headers().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, response.message());
                Log.d(TAG, response.raw().toString());
                if (userByID == null){
                    Log.e(TAG, "NULL BODY");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserByID> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return user;
    }
}
```

And my Logcat

```
--> POST http://80.193.01.777:3030/api/v1/users/auth
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 48
  
    {"email":"admin@mail.ru","password":"Admin2023"}
--> END POST (48-byte body)
<-- 302 Found http://80.193.01.777:3030/api/v1/users/auth (109ms)
    Content-Length: 154
    Content-Type: application/json
    Connection: keep-alive
{"id":1,"name":"Admin","email":"admin@mail.ru","phoneNumber":"+79763845967","password":"9c627a3e6a618 3912bf9af68283cc10112cdfd10c55d0c0f9ddba012936f335c"}
<-- END HTTP (154-byte body)
    Content-Length: 154
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Found
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=302, message=Found, url=http://80.193.01.777:3030/api/v1/users/auth}
NULL BODY
```

And server side code

```
object Users : Table() {
        val id = integer("id").autoIncrement()
        val name = varchar("name", length = 255).uniqueIndex()
        val email = varchar("email", length = 255)
        val phoneNumber = varchar("phone_number", length = 255)
        val password = varchar("password", length = 255)
        override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id)
    }
```

I tried to get raw java, but it turned out to be empty too.
The server works, if you register, everything goes well, the problem is with getting, I copied the name from the server code. And I also tried to create a new class object, fill it with the data that I get in the logs and compare with the string that I get in the logs, everything is the same, only the names are in a different order. I did not find a way how to make my class assembled and parsed in exactly the same order, but it seems like this is not necessary, the comparison is based on field names.